# How to properly filter this Route code in Laravel 5?

Tags: filter, laravel-5, filtering

I have the follow Route:

```
Route::get('/{lang?}', array('as'=>'URL',function ($lang=NULL) {

    //Retrieve the environment from URL string -> fist 2 characters.
    $env = substr(URL::route('URL'), 7, 2);
    //Store the $env inside the $_SESSION['env']
    Session::set('env', $env);

    if(is_null($lang)){
      //do some stuffs ....
    }

    return view('index');
}));
```

The goal of this code is to retrieve the URL and grab the first 2 characters that will be the evironment(`$env`).

The code expect to receive the language parameter as optional. If the user types `URL=us.mysite.com/es` the code will delivery the index page in spanish for the `US` enviroment.

If nothing is sent as language, like `URL=us.mysite.com`, there is an array inside the code that will tell the default language to `US` environment.

So far so good, it works nice.

But now I have an issue.  I would like to send the user to the home page trough the follow route code:

```
Route::get('/home', function () {
    return view('home');
});
```

The issue is that `Route::get('/home'` is going to `Route::get('/{lang?}'` and there I get an error because the code do not expect to processing this word.

After reading the documentation for [Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing), I have created filters inside the first Route code that should grab only the expected languages strings like en, sp, fr.

So this is the code now:

```
Route::get('/{lang?}', array('as'=>'URL',function ($lang=NULL) {

    //Retrieve the environment from URL string -> fist 2 characters.
    $env = substr(URL::route('URL'), 7, 2);
    //Store the $env inside the $_SESSION['env']
    Session::set('env', $env);

    if(is_null($lang)){
      //do some stuffs ....
    }

    return view('index');
}))->where('lang', '[en|es|fr]');
```

This approach is not working. Now I have this error `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:`, when I try `URL=us.mysite.com/es`, and when I try  `URL=us.mysite.com/home` I get the error `No such file or directory`.

The final goal is if the user will type `URL=us.mysite.com` without lang parameter or `URL=us.mysite.com/en or es or fr` with expected parameter the request should be processed inside the `Route::get('/{lang?}'`. If the user will type `URL=us.mysite.com/home` the request should skip the `Route::get('/{lang?}'` route and should be processed inside `Route::get('/home'`.

So, I dont know what I am doing wrong. Any idea?

Comment: Not sure how routes work and if they stop looking after a match is found, but try defining your lang route at the bottom of the routes file, so all of your other routes are before it.

Comment: Yes, it worked with this approach. I still have one issue. The filter. What am I doing wrong? Following the documentation the filter should accept regex. So `->where('lang', '[en|es|fr]')` should worked, isn't?

Comment: Yes, this should have worked, I don't know why. Maybe if you try without the brackets `'en|es|fr'`.

Comment: I think it might need a quantifier: `'[en|es|fr]+'`?

Comment: Correct.... it works now.

Comment: Another thing.... Now that it is working, I dont need to put it at the end. Because this filter seems to avoid `URL=us.mysite.com/home` to be grabbed inside  `URL=us.mysite.com/es`

Comment: Yep, glad it worked out :)